# No such file or directory when building with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, compiler-errors

I'm trying to configure and build a project with CMake.
Right now my directory tree looks like this:

```
project
  |-build
  |-CMakeLists.txt - (0)
  |-app
      |-CMakeLists.txt - (1)
      |-main.cpp
  |-submodule
      |-CMakeLists.txt - (2)
      |-src
          |-submodule
              |-submodule.cpp
              |-submodule.h
```

Content of CMakeLists.txt - (0) is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(App)

add_subdirectory(submodule)
add_subdirectory(app)
```

Content of CMakeLists.txt - (1) is:

```
add_executable(App main.cpp)

target_link_directories(App PRIVATE submodule)
```

Content of CMakeLists.txt - (2) is:

```
add_library(
    submodule
    src/submodule/submodule.cpp
    src/submodule/submodule.h
)
target_include_directories(submodule PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src")
```

Content of main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "submodule/submodule.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
        std::cout << "Not enough arguments." << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I keep getting this error when trying to build:

```
Unable to open the include file: submodule/submodule.h: No such file or directory
```

Why?

Comment: upd: found the solution: in CMakeLists.txt - (1) instead of "target_link_directories" wrote "target_link_libraries".

Answer (score 0):

Relative paths in `target_include_directories` are always resolved relative to the directory containing the `CMakeLists.txt` file containing the cmake command.

Since there's no `project/app/submodule/submodule/submodule.h` file, the include is not found via the include path you provide.

The following relative path should work:

```
add_executable(App main.cpp)

target_include_directories(App PRIVATE ../submodule/src)
```

**Note:** If you link a cmake target, the `INTERFACE` and `PUBLIC` include directories of the linked target are added to the include directories used when bilding the linking target, so linking the `submodule` cmake target to `App` would have achieved the same effect. (I assume the target is not linked with `INTERFACE` visibility in this statement.)

Comment: i did this but now there appears a linkage error for unresolved external symbol when im trying to use function from "#include "submodule/submodule.h"

Comment: just found that i had written "target_include_directories" instead of "target_link_directories" in CMakeLists.txt - (1). changed it in the answer. but now i have my previous error - no such file or directory :(